# How to filter properties from json object with rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this json object:

```
data: (85) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
labelPositions: (85) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
nodes: Array(26)
0: {id: 0, name: "CS-A", latitude: 51.84201494369347, longitude: 4.46476401684265}
1: {id: 1, name: "ZUID-E", latitude: 51.85043431186642, longitude: 4.4731833850155995}
2: {id: 2, name: "UNDEFINED", latitude: 51.852192429885925, longitude: 4.474941503035103}
3: {id: 3, name: "CS-L", latitude: 51.84773604637089, longitude: 4.470485119520069}
4: {id: 4, name: "CS-B", latitude: 51.85116783184093, longitude: 4.47391690499011}
```

with this function:

```
  showSensors() {
    this.sensorNodeService.sensorMetadata().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('sensorMetadata', data.nodes);
    });
  }
```

But now I want to get only the values from latitude and longitude. So that you will get a list like this:

[51.84201494369347, 4.46476401684265 ],
[51.85043431186642,4.4731833850155995 ]

etc.

But how to do this?

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
  showSensors() {
    this.sensorNodeService
        .sensorMetadata()
        .pipe(map((data) => data.nodes.map((node) => [node.gpsLat, node.gpsLng])))
        .subscribe((data2) => {
          console.log(data2);
        });
  }
```

But still I get

```
[undefined, undefined]
22: (2) [undefined, undefined]
23: (2) [undefined, undefined]
```

Because the api calls are generated by swagger

this is the model:

```
export interface Node {
    readonly id?: number;
    readonly name?: string | null;
    readonly gpsLat?: number;
    readonly gpsLng?: number;
}
```

So I try it like this:

```
    this.sensorNodeService.sensorMetadata().subscribe(data => {
      const latlong = data.nodes.map(node => ({latitude: node.gpsLat, longitude: node.gpsLng}));

      console.log(latlong);
      console.log(latlong[0].latitude);
    });
```

but still undeinfed

Comment: In your data they are called "longitude" and "latitude". In your code example you use "node.gpsLat" and "node.gpsLng". Change those to "node.latitude" and "node.longitude" and it should work

Comment: HI, eh, I edit the post, because the model names are different then the database tables

Comment: in database table are the names: latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create an array based on properties of another array. Try the following

```js
var data = { nodes: [
  {id: 0, name: "CS-A", latitude: 51.84201494369347, longitude: 4.46476401684265},
  {id: 1, name: "ZUID-E", latitude: 51.85043431186642, longitude: 4.4731833850155995},
  {id: 2, name: "UNDEFINED", latitude: 51.852192429885925, longitude: 4.474941503035103},
  {id: 3, name: "CS-L", latitude: 51.84773604637089, longitude: 4.470485119520069},
  {id: 4, name: "CS-B", latitude: 51.85116783184093, longitude: 4.47391690499011}
]};

const latlong = data.nodes.map(node => [node.latitude, node.longitude]);

console.log(latlong);
```

If you wish to extract this in the service level so that each call to back-end returns only the required data, you could pipe it into the service call using RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator.

**SensorNodeService**

```js
public sensorMetadata(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('someUrl').pipe(
    map(data => data.nodes.map(node => [node.gpsLat, node.gpsLng]))
  );
}
```

Now each request to the function will return the data in required format

**Component**

```js
showSensors() {
  this.sensorNodeService.sensorMetadata().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('sensorMetadata', data);  // <-- will print `[[ 51.84201494369347, 4.46476401684265 ], [ 51.85043431186642, 4.4731833850155995 ],...]`
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but the names are: node.gpsLat, node.gpsLng apparently . So I get now this[undefined, undefined]
3: (2) [undefined, undefined]

Comment: So this is the object: export interface Node {
    readonly id?: number;
    readonly name?: string | null;
    readonly gpsLat?: number;
    readonly gpsLng?: number;
}

Comment: You could just replace the `[node.latitude, node.longitude]` with `[node.gpsLat, node.gpsLng]`. I've updated the answer to also use RxJS `map` operator in the service.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton: You're now creating an array of objects. You could even see it the `console.log`. Try to do exactly this: `const latlong = data.nodes.map(node => [node.gpsLat, node.gpsLng])`.

Comment: But what is then the solutiion?

Comment: This doesnt work   this.sensorNodeService.sensorMetadata().subscribe((data) => {
      const latlong2 = data.nodes.map((node) => [node.gpsLat, node.gpsLng]);
      console.log('LOnglat2', latlong2);
    });

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by _"this doesn't work"_? Try to create a Stackblitz if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Just use standard ES6 functions, like [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
data.nodes.map(n => n.latitude)
```

or

```
data.nodes.map(n => [n.latitude, n.longitude])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var data = { nodes: [
  {id: 0, name: "CS-A", latitude: 51.84201494369347, longitude: 4.46476401684265},
  {id: 1, name: "ZUID-E", latitude: 51.85043431186642, longitude: 4.4731833850155995},
  {id: 2, name: "UNDEFINED", latitude: 51.852192429885925, longitude: 4.474941503035103},
  {id: 3, name: "CS-L", latitude: 51.84773604637089, longitude: 4.470485119520069},
  {id: 4, name: "CS-B", latitude: 51.85116783184093, longitude: 4.47391690499011}
]};

const latlong = data.nodes.map(node => ({gpsLat: node.latitude,gpsLng:node.longitude}));

console.log(latlong);
console.log(latlong[0].gpsLat);
```